# Problem after enabling Xinerama

Tags: 11.04, ati, xinerama

I enabled Xinerama and now I cant do anything. All that shows up is my mouse and background. Step by step how do I get back to normal?

I also tried opening up programs, perhaps to open Catalyst but I cant even do that. And none of the keyboard shortcuts I have tried did anything, as well I can not find a keyboard shortcut to open the terminal to kill this thing. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Enter in failsafe mode disable it done.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer myself. It is: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>. Then `sudo aticonfig --xinerama=o`

Comment: The right command is:
sudo aticonfig --xinerama=off